# Bash - Spaces in parameter passed to a function

Tags: linux, bash

I've some issue managing path with spaces passed to a function.

**a test code**

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKING_DIR="./test"
mkdir -p "$WORKING_DIR/entry-A"
mkdir -p "$WORKING_DIR/entry-B"
mkdir -p "$WORKING_DIR/entry C D E "

checkFolder() {
    echo $1 
    ls $1
}

export -f checkFolder

find $WORKING_DIR -type d -exec bash -c 'checkFolder "$@"' bash {} \;
```

**Here the output:**

```
here the output:

./test.sh 
./test
entry-A   entry-B  'entry C D E '  'entry D E '
./test/entry-A
./test/entry-B
./test/entry D E
ls: cannot access './test/entry': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'D': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'E': No such file or directory
./test/entry C D E
ls: cannot access './test/entry': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'C': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'D': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'E': No such file or directory
```

Could you suggest me the correct way to proceed in order to manage path with spaces and other special chars in this specific case?

thanks

Comment: Use double quotes: `ls "$1"`

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot this and many other common mistakes.